# PHP JQuery - Load multiple DIV's with 1 request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My site currently has to load 6 different PHP pages to fill info for 7 DIV's.

Some refresh every 5 seconds, some every second.

I would rather load the one single PHP page every second, and split the details to all of the DIV's. That way only 1 request is sent per second, rather than 3 or 4 requests.

so --> api/getdata.php will echo: "$5.93, $10.36, 27:31 1, 22, Joe". Then JQuery will need to split each comma to a different DIV. Something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {$('#balance, #pot, #timer, #round, #id, #username').load('api/getdata.php');}, 1000);
```

I had a look on Google, but couldn't find anything to what I am looking for.

My current method (very bad) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
            $('#GetBalance, #GetBalanceWithdraw').load('get/GetBalance.php');
            $('#Clock').load('get/Clock.php');
            $('#GetPot').load('get/GetPot.php');

            setTimeout(function() {$('#errmsg').fadeOut('slow');}, 5000);
            setInterval(function() {
            $('#GetPot').load('get/GetPot.php');
            $('#TotalBids').load('get/TotalBids.php');
            }, 2500); 
            setInterval(function() {$('#GetBalance, #GetBalanceWithdraw').load('get/Balance.php');}, 5000);
            setInterval(function() {$('#GetBalance').load('get/Balance.php');}, 5000);
            setInterval(function() {$('#Clock').load('get/Clock.php');}, 1000);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you will need to split your response and only then assign to elements. At this moment you add same value to all elements.

You need something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get( 'api/getdata.php', function( data ) {
        var result = data.split( ', ' );
        $( '#balance' ).text( result[ 0 ] );
        $( '#pot' ).text( result[ 1 ] );
        $( '#timer' ).text( result[ 2 ] );
        $( '#round' ).text( result[ 3 ] );
        $( '#id' ).text( result[ 4 ] );
        $( '#username' ).text( result[ 5 ] );
    } );
}, 1000);
```

But in this case you can flood you server with requests if back-end will slow with response, so better to call new AJAX after 1 second after previous loaded using recursive function:

```
function updateData() {
    $.get( 'api/getdata.php', function( data ) {
        var result = data.split( ', ' );
        $( '#balance' ).text( result[ 0 ] );
        $( '#pot' ).text( result[ 1 ] );
        $( '#timer' ).text( result[ 2 ] );
        $( '#round' ).text( result[ 3 ] );
        $( '#id' ).text( result[ 4 ] );
        $( '#username' ).text( result[ 5 ] );
        setTimeout( updateData, 1000);
    } );
}
updateData();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very simple. My site currently gets slower and slower as time goes on. That is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all your strings in one string and comma separated, you could do this:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function(data) {
  spread_the_news(data);
});
```

and then

```
function spread_the_news(data)
{
  var res = data.split(",");
  update_div_0_with_data(res[0]);
  update_div_1_with_data(res[1]);
  ...
}
```